An internal error occurred during: "Building" org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JavaRuntime.getProvidedVMPackages
enter image description here    - Image
Eclipse is showing internal error as below:
An internal error occurred during: "Building".
'java.util.Set org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JavaRuntime.getProvidedVMPackages(org.eclipse.jdt.launching.IVMInstall, java.lang.String)'
Eclipse version:
Eclipse IDE for Java Developers (includes Incubating components)
Version: 2024-03 (4.31.0)
JDK - 17 installed.
thanks in advance
Am trying yo run the program , but getting build error.

How did you install this version?

Please go to the Error Log view, select the error (do not open it, just select the row), hit Ctrl+C and paste everything (make sure it starts with eclipse.buildId= and that nothing has been cropped; if you anonymize something say so) into your question formatted as Sample Code (indented by four spaces to keep line breaks and characters like <). If more errors have been logged recently, first delete the error log and reproduce your issue. Did you installed additional plugins, e.g. for Cucumber?

Downloaded this eclipse-inst-jre-win64 and installed .  @nitind

eclipse.buildId=4.31.0.20240307-1200
java.version=17.0.10
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
!ENTRY org.eclipse.eclemma.ui 4 0 2024-07-19 19:28:06.085  org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.eclemma.ui   Chain 1:
org.jacoco.core      @howlger

Please edit your question and add all the information I have asked for.

Seems like an update to the current release from a month ago, 2024-06, might be a good first thing to try.
